# Gridsetting: Space between section and subsection (ConTeXt)

Tags: sectioning, context, grid-typesetting

Here is my Minexample

```
\mainlanguage   [de]

\definepapersize[MyBook][A5]
\setuppapersize[MyBook][A5]

\usetypescript[times]
\setupbodyfont[times,10pt]
\setupbodyfontenvironment   [default][em=italic] % use italic as em, not slanted

\setuphead[subsection][before={\blank[line]},style=bold] % Kleine subsections, besserer grid
\setuphead[section][after={\blank[line]}]

\setuplayout[grid=yes]

\showgrid
%\setupbackgrounds  [header][text][frame=off,bottomframe=on]

\starttext
Last paragraph Text.....

\section{First section}

\subsection{First Subsection}

\stoptext
```

Now you see in the grid, that the placement is not optimal. There are three lines before and after the section. It would be better to have f.e. 3 before and 1 after, or 2 before and 1 after or aynthing like that. How to achieve that?

Comment: Neither the language, paper size, page background and italic or bold settings are needed to illustrate the empty line problem. Try to construct the example as minimal as possible.

Comment: I was not sure about the paper size, typescript and font size because it determines the number of lines

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Details
manual](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/details.pdf) has
detailed explanations about grid typesetting and section head
placement on the grid. In your case you need to use the `grid=low`
setting.

```
\setuplayout
  [grid=yes]

\setuphead
  [section]
  [after=]

\setuphead
  [subsection]
  [before=,
   grid=low]

\showgrid

\starttext

Last paragraph Text.....

\startsection [title=First section]
  \startsubsection[title=First Subsection]
  \stopsubsection
\stopsection

\stoptext
```

Result:

[image: result]